# Why does it come up with an error that says that the column doesnt exist when I try and create foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I am relatively new to mysql and writing queries. I am trying to create a database that has multiple different relationships. I am able to create the tables and assign unique indexes, but when I try and alter each table, I get the same error depending on what Foreign Key I am trying to create. Here is the error I am getting:

[image]

Error Code: 1072. Key column 'gameID' doesn't exist in table

This is when I try and call

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_player` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`gameID`) REFERENCES tbl_game(`gameID`);
```

Below Is the current SQL script:

```
drop database if exists test_DB;
create database test_DB;
use test_DB;

drop procedure if exists createdb;  
delimiter //
create procedure createdb()
begin

/*Leaderboard*/
drop table if exists tbl_leaderboard;   
CREATE TABLE `tbl_leaderboard` (
    `leaderboardID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `totalScore` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `gamesPlayed` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `averageScore` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10503 PRIMARY KEY (`leaderboardID`)
);

/*User ===================================================================================*/ 
drop table if exists tbl_user; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
    `userID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `user_password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `user_email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `user_loginAttermpts` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `user_accountStatus` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `user_isAdmin` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10513 PRIMARY KEY (`userID`,`username`)
);

/*Player  ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_player; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_player` (
    `player_score` SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `playerID` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `colour` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10375 PRIMARY KEY (`player_score`,`playerID`)
);

/*Inventory ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_inventory;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_inventory` (
    `inventoryID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `quantity` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10520 PRIMARY KEY (`inventoryID`)
);

/*Tile ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_tile;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_tile` (
    `tileID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10547 PRIMARY KEY (`tileID`)
    
);

/*Board ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_board;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_board` (
    `boardID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10538 PRIMARY KEY (`boardID`)
    
);

/*Game ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_game;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_game` (
    `gameID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `gameNumber` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `numberOfPlayers` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `gameMode` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10543 PRIMARY KEY (`gameID`)
);

/*Chat ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_gameChat;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_gameChat` (
    `chatID` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `text` VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10555 PRIMARY KEY (`chatID`)
);

/*TileAsset ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_assetTile;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_assetTile` (
    `assetTileID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10545 PRIMARY KEY (`assetTileID`)
);

/*Asset ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_asset;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_asset` (
    `assetID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `asset_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `asset_type` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `asset_value` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10557 PRIMARY KEY (`assetID`)
);

/*Create UNIQUE Indexes*/
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10503_10504 ON `tbl_leaderboard` (`leaderboardID`);
    
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10497_10498 ON `tbl_user` (`userID`,`username`);
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10513_10514 ON `tbl_user` (`userID`,`username`);
    
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10375_10376 ON `tbl_player` (`player_score`,`playerID`);
    
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10520_10521 ON `tbl_inventory` (`inventoryID`);
    
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10547_10548 ON `tbl_tile` (`tileID`);
    
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10538_10539 ON `tbl_board` (`boardID`);
    
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10543_10544 ON `tbl_game` (`gameID`);
    
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10555_10556 ON `tbl_gameChat` (`chatID`);
    
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10545_10546 ON `tbl_assetTile` (`assetTileID`);
    
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10557_10558 ON `tbl_asset` (`assetID`);


/*Add Foreign Keys*/
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_player` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`gameID`) REFERENCES tbl_game(`gameID`);
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_player` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`tileID`) REFERENCES tbl_tile(`tileID`);
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_player` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES tbl_user(`userID`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_inventory` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`playerID`) REFERENCES tbl_player(`playerID`);
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_inventory` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`assetID`) REFERENCES tbl_asset(`assetID`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_tile` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`boardID`) REFERENCES tbl_board(`boardID`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_board` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`gameID`) REFERENCES tbl_game(`gameID`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_gameChat` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`gameID`) REFERENCES tbl_game(`gameID`);
    
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_assetTile` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`tileID`) REFERENCES tbl_tile(`tileID`);
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_assetTile` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`assetID`) REFERENCES tbl_asset(`assetID`);

    ALTER TABLE `tbl_leaderboard` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`player_score`) REFERENCES tbl_player(`player_score`);
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_leaderboard` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES tbl_user(`userID`);
    ALTER TABLE `tbl_leaderboard` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES tbl_user(`username`);

    
end //

delimiter ;
call createdb();
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated and possible improvements to the fomrmat.

Comment: Well, `tbl_player` doesn't have a `gameID` column. So the error is entirely correct. Nor does it have `tileID` or `userID`. In fact, I believe none of the columns used in your FK's exist

Comment: Simplify, remove all stuff not needed to reproduce the problem! [mcve], https://betterprogramming.pub/find-and-fix-bugs-like-a-pro-with-divide-and-conquer-d55f3cf91154

Answer (score 0):

Your table `tbl_player` doesn't have a column `gameID` add it in you create script to add the `FOREIGN KEY`, the same applies to all foreign keys you are trying to add. the column must be available in the table where you are willing to create the `FOREIGN KEY`

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_player` (
    `player_score` SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `playerID` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `colour` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `gameID` INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10375 PRIMARY KEY (`player_score`,`playerID`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before creating foreign keys for any table, make sure the table contains/has the column you are adding foreign key constraint to.

In your case if you see the table `tbl_player` (as you have shared)

```
/*Player  ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_player; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_player` (
    `player_score` SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `playerID` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `colour` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10375 PRIMARY KEY (`player_score`,`playerID`)
);
```

does not have column `gameID` and the query you are running `` ALTER TABLE `tbl_player` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`gameID`) REFERENCES tbl_game(`gameID`); ``  is trying to add **Foreign key** constraint on column `gameID` *(which does not exists in the **tbl_player** table)* thereby resulting into an error you mentioned `Error Code: 1072. Key column 'gameID' doesn't exist in table`

To solve this you can :

1. Alter table to add a new column and then add foreign key constraint to that column :

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_player
  ADD COLUMN gameID INT,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_name(gameID) REFERENCES tbl_game(gameID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

2. Add a column `gameID` while creating the table as below :

```
/*Player  ===================================================================================*/
drop table if exists tbl_player; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_player` (
    `player_score` SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `playerID` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    `colour` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `gameID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT SYS_PK_10375 PRIMARY KEY (`player_score`,`playerID`)
);
```

then alter the table to create column `gameID` as foreign key :

`ALTER TABLE tbl_player add FOREIGN KEY(gameID) REFERENCES tbl_game(gameID);`

Any one of the above points should work.

Cheers!!